# Sql Cleanup script, delete from one table that's not in the other

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-400

We wrote a cleanup script in SQL(DB2) as400 to do cleanup of tables. ps we are fixing the processes that is causing the data issues.

The SQL : `DELETE FROM p6prodpf A WHERE (0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P6OPIPF B WHERE B.OPIID = A.OPIID))`

Its simple code to check if theres a record in `p6prodpf` that has no record in `P6OPIPF` then delete the record in `p6prodpf`.

My problem that I am facing is that there's instances where the `p6prodpf` is being deleted even if theres a record in `P6OPIPF`.

Is there a better way of doing this or safer way.. Is there any reason why this could be happening.

The script runs 3am in the morning.

It also feels like a sequencing issue but when I check the record in `P6OPIPF` it exists but its deleted in `p6prodpf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "NOT EXISTS" instead of "0 =":

```
DELETE FROM p6prodpf A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM P6OPIPF B WHERE B.OPIID = A.OPIID)
```

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` *is* a better choice.  But I don't see how this fixes the problem the OP mentions.

Comment: Also, If the script runs BEFORE matching records were added to P6OPIPF, this could also explain your problem.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff, `NOT EXISTS` is a better choice, but shouldn't work any differently.  Russ is probably on the right track with the script being run to delete from `P6PRODOF` before the records are added to `P6OPIPF`.  I suggest using the journals to determine when the records are being added.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am going to use journals to determine when the records are being added and what sequence this is happening. I will update the answer when I know what caused my problem.